# How to print newline inside concat of xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I want to separate my output with a newline, so I tried:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//node01" -v 'concat(@title,"\n",script/code)' -n input.xml
```

However, what is printed is the "\n" literal value and the output is on same line. How do I force a newline within the concat() function?

A sample input.xml is:

```
<test>
<aaa>This is a test</aaa>
<node01 title="howdy">
    <script>
        <code>function idoit() {
                console.log("hello world");
            }
        </code>
    </script>
</node01>
</test>
```

And when I run, the output is:

```
howdy\nfunction idoit() {
                console.log("hello world");
            }
```

Comment: What happens when you try `concat(@title,"&#10;",script/code)`? Isn't xmlstarlet simply creating some XSLT from your input where perhaps then the character reference works?

Comment: hi Martin, nice tip but i tried it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a literal newline in the argument, the syntax for this is shell-specific.

- This should work in any POSIX `sh`:

  ```
  xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//node01" -v 'concat(@title,"
  ",script/code)' -n input.xml
  ```
- In bash, you can use [$'ANSI C Quoting'](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html):

  ```
  xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//node01" -v $'concat(@title,"\n",script/code)' -n input.xml
  ```

Another trick which is not shell-specific is to set an XPATH variable with newline as the value:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t --var nl -n -b -m "//node01" -v 'concat(@title,$nl,script/code)' -n input.xml
```